# Guava Multimaps wildcard putAll

Tags: java, generics, guava

Struggling with a generics issue using Guava's Multimap

```
class Foo{
    ...
    private Multimap<Baz,? extends Bar> stuff;
    ...

    public void overWriteStuff(Multimap<Baz,? extends Bar> newstuff){
         this.stuff.clear();
         this.stuff.putAll(newStuff);
    }
 }
```

This looks very straighforward to me, both `stuff` and the argument `newstuff` both have the same type yet I get a generics related compiler exception:

`The method putAll(Multimap<? extends Baz,? extends capture#8-of ? extends Bar>) in the type 
 Multimap<Baz,capture#8-of ? extends Bar> is not applicable for the arguments (Multimap<Baz,capture#9-of ? 
 extends Bar>)`

Can anyone see where my generics screw up is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `? extends Bar` means "some *specific* (but unknown) subtype of `Bar`". You don't know, for either the field in your class or for the parmater to your method, what actual type of values the multimap holds.

For example, if you have two classes `Foo extends Bar` and `Blah extends Bar`, you could assign a `Multimap<Baz, Foo>` to `stuff` and pass a `Multimap<Baz, Blah>` to your method as `newstuff`. If `stuff.putAll(newstuff)` were allowed, you'd then have `stuff` being a multimap that claims all of its values are instances of `Foo`, when in fact some of them are instead instances of `Blah`.

Perhaps you actually just want `stuff` to be a `Multimap<Baz, Bar>`? In that case its values can be any kind of `Bar` and your method will work fine. Another option, as @rgettman mentions, is to introduce a type variable `T extends Bar` to ensure that the values of `stuff` and `newstuff` are both the *same* subtype of `Bar`; which you do depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isn't that the whole point of the `<? extends>` notation. In your example both Foo and Blah extend Bar. So wouldn't <? extends Bar> cover those cases?

Comment: No, I think you're misunderstanding `? extends`. Like I said, `? extends Bar` refers to a _specific but unknown_ subtype of `Bar`. Because of that, two `? extends Bar` are incompatible because the actual value for each could be a _different_ subtype. The type that refers to `Bar` and any/all subtypes of it is just plain old `Bar`.

Comment: Thanks to both ColinD and @rgettman for the answers. Both of which helped me understand the issue (and generics better). I'm torn since both answers were correct. I will award the answer to ColinD and vote up the answer by rgettman.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` wildcard from the original declaration cannot match the `?` wildcard from the parameter.  They could be any subclass of `Bar` (or `Bar` itself), and they do not have to match.

You need to introduce a generic type parameter on `Foo` to replace the wildcards, so that they will represent the same type.

```
class Foo<T extends Bar>{
```

In the variable declaration:

```
private Multimap<Baz, T> stuff;
```

And in the method parameter:

```
public void overWriteStuff(Multimap<Baz, T> newstuff){
```

Incidentally, this has everything to do with Java's generics but nothing to do with Guava.  I could replicate the error with a `Map` replacing the `Multimap`.

Comment: But I don't wish to limit the Multimap (or Map as you point out) to contain values of a specific type T. I want the map to hold all subtypes Bar. In your example won't that mean the only valid type for values in the Map are of type T and ONLY of type T?

Comment: If you want to hold all subtypes of `Bar`, then you don't need `T`, you just need a `Multimap<Baz, Bar>`.